# How can I insert in two different tables from the same form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

How can I insert in two different tables from the same form ?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO CLINET (IDMAT, TYPE, MARQUE,MODEL,PRIXACH,PRIXV)
VALUES
('$_POST[id_mat]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[marque]','$_POST[model]'),$_POST[prixach]','$_POST[prixv]'";

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO FOURNIR(IDFOUR, QTTE, IDMAT)
VALUES
('$_POST[id_four]','$_POST[qtte]','$_POST[id_mat]','$_POST[model]');
```

Comment: You answered your own question. However your database is open to injection

Comment: Yes i know that i answer to my question , but how i can make it better than that ??

Comment: By asking a more relevant question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO CLINET (IDMAT, TYPE, MARQUE,MODEL,PRIXACH,PRIXV)
VALUES
('$_POST[id_mat]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[marque]','$_POST[model]'),$_POST[prixach]','$_POST[prixv]'";

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO FOURNIR(IDFOUR, QTTE, IDMAT)
VALUES
('$_POST[id_four]','$_POST[qtte]','$_POST[id_mat]','$_POST[model]');
```

For the first query your missing a ')' at the end of your values.

For the second query, You have three column names, and four values. The amount of columns must match the amount of values.

Try checking basic syntax next time.